# Parse Server vs. Meteor - differences?

Tags: meteor, parse-platform, ionic-framework, parse-server

I wanna build a mobile app with the ionic framework that

- stores Users
- stores Friends
- stores Information between them
- provides an administration view
- has some server side calculation to safe the mobile's battery

I already watched some tutorials about parse server, but heard of meteor. 
The App don't have to be uuultra real-time.

I just wanna push the data to the server, and get some data back (with some server side calculation)

All information i found so far are about a year old, so meteor always won, because parse cost in those days. 
Today, Parse Server is open source and free.

What are the **main differences between meteor** and Parse Server?
And what would you use? - and why!

Thx,
Kevin

Comment: I would use neither ;-) Parse is shutting down, the code has been open sourced but without corporate backing you are unlikely to see much development. Meteor (the company) is focusing on other stuff than Meteor (the framework), and have pretty much left development to the community as well (although some limited development effort is still going on). So both alternatives are pretty much at end-of-life.

Comment: Your requirements seem simple. Meteor will do fine (don't know about parse server), Meteor is still active, even though MDG have other things on. This question, however, will attract opinionated answers (as it has already), so is really off-topic for SO

Comment: I think, the Parse.com shutdown isn't that wrong. Facebook put much development in it ($30Million) and now it's open source, you could host your own Parse Server in a few minutes. with angular-meteor the meteor framework has a huge framework. But what would you use, if you would use neither of those two?

Answer (score 2):

I've used them both, but not deep into them. The most difference is building app I think:

- Parse, that allows user to use native android/ios api, and provides its own sdk for user.
- Meteor, that allows user to use html/css way to write code, and provides command tool to build android/ios app.

And currently, Meteor on Windows does not support mobile builds.